# laravel query filter with havingRAW not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

I have a 'villas' table as 'Villa' model and it has a 'BookingPlans' relationship model with table 'booking_plans';
each row of **BookingPlan** has a 'villa_id' and 'rate' column which stores the price/night for a certain date.
now I'm trying to achieve a search filter for rates (user input Min or Max rate) but I'm badly stuck.

(( Laravel 7+ , PHP 7 ))
Here is my Controller

```
        $villas->active();
        
        if($request->leastRate >= 1){
            $villas->filterMinRate($request->leastRate);
        }

        if($request->maxRate >= 1){
            $villas->filterMaxRate($request->maxRate);
        }
```

and here is My Villa model

```
    public function scopeFilterMinRate($q,int $rate){
        return $q->whereHas('bookingPlans',function($qu) use ($rate){
            $qu->select('rate')->havingRaw("MIN(rate) > $rate");
        });
        
    }
```

and What I need to get to is, for each villa, find the Min. rate for all dates, then apply the user input Min. rate to it to filter and display only villas whose Min. rate is greater than the User's input min. rate.

but it doesn't work and I have googled and tried lots of different approaches. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: try  `->havingRaw('MIN(rate) > ?', [$rate])`

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out myself guys.

SOLVED .. a very stupid mistake, Datatype of database(varchar) was not in agreement with of input $rate (integer)